# DoctrineODM Priming of Multi-Level References

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

Sorry for the awkward title but I have no better naming for the issue (comments on how to properly name the question are welcome).

Let's say I have 3 Documents:

- Category
- Product
- Version

A Category has many Products. A Product has many Versions.
Now I want to Query for all Categories and list all Products and Versions of each Category.

I know about priming [priming](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/priming-references.html).

Is it possible to write a query like:

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Category')
    ->field('products')->prime(true)
    ->field('products.versions')->prime(true)
$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright it seems that in the current state doctrine-odm does not support multi-level priming. This is a known issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/624).

I found a solution in the GitHub Issue that passes a closure to the prime method to allow at least two level priming. Hope this helps someone.

```
$myPrimer = function(DocumentManager $dm, ClassMetadata $class, array $ids, array $hints) {
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder($class->name)
        ->field($class->identifier)->in($ids);

    if ( ! empty($hints[Query::HINT_SLAVE_OKAY])) {
        $qb->slaveOkay(true);
    }

    if ( ! empty($hints[Query::HINT_READ_PREFERENCE])) {
        $qb->setReadPreference($hints[Query::HINT_READ_PREFERENCE], $hints[Query::HINT_READ_PREFERENCE_TAGS]);
    }

    $results = $qb->getQuery()->toArray();

    $nestedPrimers = array(
        'address' => true, // List of fields to prime
    );

    $uow = $dm->getUnitOfWork();
    $referencePrimer = new ReferencePrimer($dm, $uow);

    foreach ($nestedPrimers as $fieldName => $primer) {
        $primer = is_callable($primer) ? $primer : null;
        $referencePrimer->primeReferences($class, $results, $fieldName, $hints, $primer);
    }
};
```

The Closure can the be passed to the Primer:

```
->field('club')->prime($myPrime)
```